# setTimeout not updating when in loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to update a progress tag whose value is counter in a for loop, however it seems that the timeout is paused while JavaScript executes my for loop. Code:

```js
function run() {
  var progressbar = document.getElementById("update");
  var items = Array(100).fill().map(() => Math.round(Math.random()));

  var i = 0;

  progressbar.max = items.length - 1;
  (function pbincrement() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      progressbar.value = i;
      console.log("Value update")
      if (progressbar.value < progressbar.max) pbincrement();
    }, 1);
  })();

  var results = [];
  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    // Something with the item
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="run()">Click me!</button>
<progress id="update" value=0></progress>
```

How do I properly make the progressbar follow the loop counter, instead of only updating when the loop is done running?

Comment: You can't, even if you update the progress bar inside the loop. See [Jake Archibald's talk on the event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0&vl=en). What you can do instead is use async code so the browser has a chance to update the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than [`for()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop independently, use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) to iterate over the `items` array:

```js
function run () {
  let results = [], i = 0;

  let progressbar = document.getElementById("update");
  let items = Array(50).fill().map(() => Math.round(Math.random()));
  progressbar.max = items.length - 1;

  (function pbincrement () {
    setTimeout(() => {

        // execute this block with each step of items array interation
        if ( progressbar.max >= i ) {

          // do something with the current item array element
          results.push(items[i]);
          console.log(i, items[i]);
          
          // update the progress bar and increment item array
          progressbar.value = i++;
          pbincrement(); // repeat setTimeout
        } 

        // after iteration completes
        else {
          console.log(results);
        }
      }, 10);
  }());
}
```

```html
<button onclick="run()">Click me!</button>
<progress id="update" value=0></progress>
```

OR use Javascript [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) to iterate your `items` array and update your progress bar with each interval:

```js
function run () {
  let results = [], i = 0;

  let progressbar = document.getElementById("update");
  let items = Array(10).fill().map(() => Math.round(Math.random()));
  progressbar.max = items.length - 1;

  let iid = setInterval(
    function () {
    
      // each step of items array interation
      if ( progressbar.max >= i ) {
        console.log(i, items[i]);
        results.push(items[i]);
        progressbar.value = i++;
      } 
      
      // after iteration completes
      else {
        clearInterval(iid);
        console.log(results);
      }
    }, 1);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="run()">Click me!</button>
<progress id="update" value=0></progress>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working asynchronous solution. I recommend watching the talk linked in caTS's comment.

```js
function run() {
  var progressbar = document.getElementById("update");
  var items = Array(100).fill().map(() => Math.round(Math.random()));
  var i = 0;
  var results = [];
  (async () => {
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      console.log(i);
      progressbar.value = (i / items.length)
      await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 200))
    }
  })()
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="run()">Click me!</button>
<progress id="update" value=0></progress>
```

Here's a demonstration of how, even when synchronous but 'paused' (blocked) using `alert()` for us to see what's happening, the DOM still doesn't get updated after each loop iteration.

```js
function run() {
  var progressbar = document.getElementById("update");
  var items = Array(4).fill().map(() => Math.round(Math.random()));
  var i = 0;
  var results = [];
  for (i = 0; i <= items.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    progressbar.value = (i / items.length)
    alert(i);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="run()">Click me!</button>
<progress id="update" value=0></progress>
```